# How do you take an image (passed in as a Base64 encoded string) and save it to the server in Asp.Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, file, base64

I want to create a function like this...

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SaveImage(string file, string fileName)
    {

    }
```

Where the file is the Base64 encoded string created from the image, and the fileName is the name I want to save it as. How can I use this encoded string to write the image to the server?

Do I need to use `BinaryWriter` or `TextWriter` or some other one? And how do you decode the data to allow it to write to the server properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
byte[] contents = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(fileName), contents);
```

Comment: Gives me an error "System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(string, string, string)  is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context"
The method that handles this is in a controller... what do I need to do to get rid of the error?

Comment: Oops, it's a name collision issue between Controller.File method and System.IO.File class. Just name the complete thing to fix. Editing